# bash script that automates downloading and installing an app

Tags: shell-script, apt

I want to write a bash script that automates the downloading and installing process of an app. As I test this script I don't want to download the package over and over again.

1. Does apt-get have something similar to aptitude's dry run seen
   [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-simulate-package-upgrade/)? Or is simply commenting the `apt-get install <package>` and
   assuming it works the best bang for my buck?
2. What about pointing `apt-get install <package>` to `dev/null`?
3. This script will be ran on a VM is there anything I should keep in mind when writing a bash script for a VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**apt** also have `dry-run`. From the man-page:

> -s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
>
> No action. Perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually change the system.  Configuration Item:
>   APT::Get::Simulate. Simulate prints out a series of lines, each one
>   representing an rpm
>       operation: Configure (Conf), Remove (Remv), Unpack (Inst). Square brackets indicate broken packages with an empty set of square brackets
>   meaning breaks that are of no consequence (rare).

So something trivially like :

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get -s -y install <package>
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo 'Package installed' ; else echo 'Error'; exit ; fi
```

Depends in what concept you want to use it.

2. This won't install packages.
3. As for VM, I don't see any issues.